# Using an Android and iOS application as a feature inside another application

Tags: android, ios, plugins, package

I have a standalone Android and iOS application and my customer also wants this application to work as a feature inside his other application, like clicking on a button and open my application inside his application not switching between applications. I wanted to know if there are any ways I can use my application this way and what are the best security practices to not reveal my source code.
thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a JAR of your app and an API for your customer. Your customer can then use your "app" like it's a part of their own, you can define the specific interactions while also using Proguard (or whatever) to protect your code.

This also would allow for you to have a standalone app and provide for good version control. And users hate to install 2 apps to get full functionality, in general.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, but my case is simpler than providing an API. I just want my app to be opened and launched inside another app without being an stand alone app and user only installs one app. I want the other app to call my app like an intent or something, and there are no need for interactions between two packages

Comment: Then you would still create a JAR and your API consists only of calls to launch activities within it. "API" does mean "complicated" - in your case it may be only 2 or 3 interface definitions, but it is still an API (Application Programming Interface) because you are creating an "interface" between "applications" - which is specifically what you asked about